# Why Copy constructor is called along with Move Constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

This problem seems strange but I've checked with multiple compilers. In my code, I have a `Move Constructor` and a `copy constructor` as

```
class A {
    int val;
public:
    A(int var) : val(var)  {
    }
    A( A && a1) {
        cout<<"M Value -> "<<a1.val<<endl;
        cout<<"Move Cons..."<<endl;
     }
    A(const A & a1) {
        cout<<"Copy Cons.."<<endl;
        cout<<"Value -> "<<a1.val<<endl;
    }
};
```

If I write my `main` function as

```
int main()
{
    vector<A> v1;
    A a2(200);
    v1.push_back(move(a2));              
}
```

The output is

```
M Value -> 200
Move Cons...
```

Which is expected, but if I changed my `main` function as

```
int main()
{
    vector<A> v1;
    A a2(200);
    v1.push_back(A(100));
    v1.push_back(move(a2));

}
```

I get the following output

```
M Value -> 100
Move Cons...
M Value -> 200
Move Cons...
Copy Cons..   // unexpected
Value -> 0    // unexpected
```

Can anyone help me in understanding where and how this `copy constructor` gets called.. that too with value `0`

Thanks

Comment: Vector needs to re-allocate its storage in order to grow, and copies the first element over to the new storage. Mark the move constructor `noexcept`, then a good implementation would be able to move the element instead.

Comment: As to value 0 - your copy and move constructors don't actually copy anything, and leave `this->val` uninitialized. Your program exhibits undefined behavior when such an object is further moved or copied, by way of accessing uninitialized object. In your case, the unpredictable value in `val` just happens to be 0.

Comment: Most (at least if they are conforming) standard library implementations of `std::vector` will only move elements when they grow if the elements they contain satisfy [std::move_if_noexcept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move_if_noexcept) since `vector` needs to implement the strong exception guarantee. If they cannot move they will fall back to copy. Make your move constructor `noexcept`.

Comment: You can also reserve storage before pushing back to avoid reallocations in vector: `v1.reserve(2);`.

Comment: Daksh, I answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons were already answered in the comments.
I will try to illustrate what's going on.

## Steps:

`vector<A> v1;`

1. Allocation of the vector. It internally reserves space for one element.

`v1.push_back(A(100));`

2. Construct and the move of `A(100)` inside the vector.

`v1.push_back(move(a2));`

3. Since you are trying to insert a new element, exceeding actual maximum size, vector it's reallocated to a new memory space. Remember that `std::vector` keeps its content in contiguous memory.
4. Move `a2` inside the `v1`.
5. Copy the rest of elements (in this case only the first one) of original `v1` to the new `v1`.

## Memory:

```
1) ## v1[undef ] #########################
2) ## v1[A(100)] #########################
3) ##   [A(100)] ### v1[undef,  undef ] ##
4) ##   [A(100)] ### v1[undef,  A(200)] ##
5) ##   [A(100)] ### v1[A(100), A(200)] ##
```

## Additional notes:

Related to the value 0, that's because these copy and move constructors actually do nothing and `val` value remain undefined.
With proper constructors, this log should be 100.

If you mark the move constructor as `noexcept`, it will be used in the reallocation process instead of the copy one.

You can use `v1.emplace_back(100)` instead of `v1.push_back(A(100))` avoiding move.

Comment: empty vector probably didn't allocate space for one element, but the first resize was invisible

Comment: @Caleth, You are most probably right. Since vector grows is implementation dependent and we don’t use an explicit resize, it is unclear. So I tried to maintain it as simple as possible for clarity.